# How to Preview a Lightning App in Visual Studio code?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, visualstudiocode

Hi so i'm new to salesforce developement and recently i switched from the developer console to the Visual studio code to develop components there , but the thing is i don't know how to actually preview my App from the visual studio code , Any help please?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to create a lightning app inside your aura folder, then push your changes to your scratch org. Once it's done open the URL.

The URL pattern is https://instance.lightning.force.com/[namespace]/[app_name].app.

App example:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:yourcomponent />
</aura:application>
```

Steps:

1. SFDX: Push Source to default Scratch Org and Overwrite Conflicts
2. SFDX: Open Default Scratch Org
3. Access https://instance.lightning.force.com/[namespace]/[app_name].app

I hope this may help.